# JavaFX Screen.getPrimary().getBounds() returns incorrect screen size

Tags: javafx

I have interesting problem when trying to get resolution (not pixel count but current working resolution) of user's monitor on Windows device. `Screen.getPrimary().getBounds()` returns correct result on ALMOST all systems. It has problems with Win 10 laptops. Their resolution is recognized as 1280x768 even if they are 4K and FullHD devices.

I also tried following approaches:

- `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()`
- `Screen.getScreens()` and then iterate through all screens (only one is found)
- `GraphicsDevice getDisplayMode().getWidth();`
- `GraphicsEnvironment getScreenDevices()` and then iterate through all screens (only one is found)

I have no more ideas. Is there some other way on how to correctly get screen resolution on ALL windows devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I neither know your devices nor Windows 10 in particular but there is one thing you should keep in mind. The reported size is not the physical pixel size of the device. Instead the scaled size is reported. On Windows this depends on the display settings of your device. My Mac for example has a physical pixel size of 2880x1800 but the reported size is 1440x900. Depending on your settings this is not always a factor of exactly 2.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to mention that FullHD laptop reports correct resolution when we set it on some lower value (eg. 1600x900). It "lies" only on certain resolutions! And yes, I would be fine if it reported scaled resolution correctly but even those values are not correct every time...

Comment: No, I am not talking about changing the resolution. I am talking about the default text size settings. I don't know how that is called in Windows.

Comment: Ah, I misunrestood you. You are right! That can be the problem. I will check it right now!

Comment: I confirm you were right. When I tried this test case I managed to get different values as expected:  `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` - returned pixels and `Screen.getPrimary().getBounds()` - returned scaled values. I will accept your answer as correct one. Thnx.